# Why is this JSON String invalid? jQuery.parseJSON function throws invalid character

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp, servlets

When trying to parse the JSON being returned by my Serlvet to my JSP page the following line of code is throwing a invalid character exception :

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

**CLIENT SIDE CODE**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        function updateProgrammerDetails(site, Id) {

            $.post('EngineAdminServlet',
                    {
                        action: "updateProgrammerMenu",
                        siteDetails: site,
                        ID: Id,
                    }, 
                    function(data, status){
                        var pid, name, sky, ip, eleven;
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                        .........


                        }   
                    }).fail(function(error) { 
                        alert("Error retrieving details from server");
            }); //end ajax call
        }
</script>
```

**JSON STRING GENERATED USING GSON**

I've imported the GSON library in my Servlet class in order to convert my Java object 'ProgrammerForJSP' to a JSON string. This was recommended on other posts to avoid any typos when creating the JSON string myself. This is the string it  returned:

```
{"ID":123,"siteName":"VEGAS","skyl":"WZ0019","ipAddress":"0.0.0.0","code":"L/BEG"}
```

**SERVLET CODE**

```
.... 

response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String gson = new Gson().toJson(myObject);
response.getWriter().write(gson);
} //end of method
```

I don't know if I'm missing a step or doing something wrong? My thought is that the IP address field might be throwing off the parser and breaking the code (hence the invalid character exception) because it contains period characters in it? I really have no idea.

**EDIT**
I'm using jquery-1.11.3.js

Comment: Sorry @rory this was a rushed post so I've probably not explained very well. I've posted to my servlet an ID along with some other attributes from my JSP page which are then used to create a object on the servlet. This object is then parsed to a JSON string using Gson so that I can get some of the attributes from the object and fill some fields on my JSP page when it's returned. However, this is when the error is occuring: when I'm trying to parse back to an object on the JSP page it is throwing the invalid character exception, so I can't loop over my object to get values from it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because the `$.post` method has already detected a JSON response and parsed the result to an object for you. You are then trying to call `parseJSON` on an object instead of a JSON string, which results in the error you've seen. You simply need to remove the call to `$.parseJSON`. Try this:

```js
function updateProgrammerDetails(site, Id) {
    $.post('EngineAdminServlet', {
        action: "updateProgrammerMenu",
        siteDetails: site,
        ID: Id,
    }, function(data, status) {
        var pid, name, sky, ip, eleven;
        // work with the object in 'data' here, E.g:
        console.log(data.ID, data.siteName); // = 123, 'VEGAS'
    }).fail(function(error) { 
        alert("Error retrieving details from server");
    }); //end ajax call
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rory . I didn't realise that the object was parsed when defining the response content-type. I had seen other examples on the web use the `jQuery.parseJSON()` even when setting the response type. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.